# nodejs mongodb createCollection fails to return error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongodb native driver for nodejs and it appears to fail to return an error from the createCollection callback when an invalid request is made to server.  See this snippet that does not fail.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, mongoOpts, function (err, db) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var name = 'example';
    var settings = {
        invalid: 'invalid type',
        j: 123
    };

    db.createCollection(name, settings, function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
           throw err;
        }
        console.log(result);
        db.close();

    });

});
```

Comment: That's normal as any fields in the options parameter that aren't recognized are just ignored.

Comment: Pretty poor if types aren't checked properly, the key j is valid in this snippet however its type is not so an error should be returned.

Comment: For a boolean argument like `j`, it's pretty typical to evaluate the value's truthiness rather than require a strict boolean.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by JohnnyHK the mongo shell and nodejs driver ignores invalid keys and types when creating a collection which means writing a test to expect an error is difficult.  An issue was raised on jira as ref SERVER-7101.  The way to force an error is to pass a null or undefined as the collection name to method.

Comment: Issue on Jira is SERVER-7101